# overwriting column values when using df.at

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I wrote a function that reads in a csv file, performs some calculations and writes output to the same file. To append the calculated values to a new column, I'm using `df.at[index, column_name] = value`.

This is my code

```
def total_calc(n):
     input = pd.read_csv(file_name)
     input['calc'] = 0.0
     for index, row in input.iterrows():

       # perform calculations

     input.at[index, 'calc'] = calc_value
     input.to_csv(file_name, index=False)
```

When I use the function for multiple values of n, it is writing the values in the same column overwriting the values of previous n values in the dataframe. 
I tried using i in the function and giving `index+i`, something like this:

```
def total_calc(i,n):
     input = pd.read_csv(file_name)
     input['calc'] = 0.0
     for index, row in input.iterrows():

       # perform calculations

     input.at[index+i, 'calc'] = calc_value
     input.to_csv(file_name, index=False)

total_calc(1,2)
total_calc(2,8)
```

However, the column values are still overwritten. Is there any way to write the columns for multiple values in the function to the same file without overwriting?

so these are my current dataset columns

```
names values wickets score
```

I need this after running all required functions

```
names values wickets score calc calc1 calc2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need loop by `range` and value `k` add to column name - each loop is created another column:

```
def total_calc(i,n):

     for k in range(n):
         input = pd.read_csv(file_name)
         input['calc' + str(i)] = 0.0
         for index, row in input.iterrows():

           # perform calculations

         input.at[index, 'calc' + str(i)] = calc_value

     input.to_csv(file_name, index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @jezrael. I just tried doing this but it still overwrites the values of previous function. Can I use anything else other than df.at?

Comment: if for each call function create new column with different name, how it is possible? Maybe I dont understand what need.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I edited the question. Maybe it makes it clear.

Comment: Thanks @jezrael. Sorry couldn't check it in the morning. I'll try this code and see how it works out. Also, I realised that the file is being read each time within the loop and it isn't saving the column. So, maybe I need to read the file outside the loop and write to the saved file each time. I am working on this method as well and will post it here if it works.

Comment: @Jhonny - I think the best is if calculation is replace by something similar, e.g. `row = row + 1`. then is possible add to question sample data, e.g. 5 rows, 2 columns and add expected output? Because now question is very unclear. thanks.

Comment: Sure that's also a method I could try. Thanks @jezrael.

Comment: Yeah exactly! Sorry for the ambiguity in the question. Once I get my required answer, I'll post it here so that the clear answer and method would be available to others in the future. You're helpful as always, thanks @jezrael!

Comment: @Jhonny - You are welcome! If still some problem, let me know ;)

Answer (score 0):

So just a single change in my code got my required answer. I gave the input file just out of the loop and it worked!

```
input = pd.read_csv(file_name)
def total_calc(i,n):
     input['calc'] = 0.0
     for index, row in input.iterrows():

       # perform calculations

     input.at[index+i, 'calc'] = calc_value
     input.to_csv(file_name, index=False)

total_calc(1,2)
total_calc(2,8)
```

the above answer is useful if there are huge number of columns to be added but since mine required only three, this answer worked fine for me.